# Codename One: QR code scanner with Zxing

Tags: java, zxing, codenameone

I'm developing a mobile app(android & ios), which enables user to scan QR code, using Zxing.

At this moment, I've tried out the QR scanner demo provided in [codenameone_docs_demos_20130307.zip](http://www.codenameone.com/download.html), which works in Ipad.

---

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to configure the scan area, to be smaller? (The default demo is difficult for me to scan SMALL QR code, the default scanning area is too big)
2. Is there a way to configure the scanner UI? E.g: a line or point, to facilitate user to focus.

---

Deeply appreciated if someone could give me an advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible only by customizing the ZXing apps native code. So yes but that would be pretty difficult.